# Flex box to assign largest child width to other child width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a group of child whose width should be similar. To be simple child with largest width should be assigned to other child. I tried using `flexbox` but not able to get it. Is it possible to achieve in flex box or should i go for `JS` solution. Refer my example which i tried. Please don't post any javascript answer for it.

```css
.flex{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:baseline
}
.flex > div{
  background:#aaa
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
      Text to check
  </div>
    <div>
      Text to check for similar width
  </div>
   <div>
      Text to check for similar width - will it work
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `display:inline-flex;` and give the items a width of 100%.

```css
.flex{
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:baseline
}
.flex > div{
  background:#aaa;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
      Text to check
  </div>
    <div>
      Text to check for similar width
  </div>
   <div>
      Text to check for similar width - will it work
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Updated, thanks to* *@vals* *[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319932/flex-box-to-assign-largest-child-width-to-other-child-width/43319991#comment73714163_43319991)*

Or change to `align-items: stretch` on the `container` and drop the `width: 100%` on the items.

```css
.flex{
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:stretch;
}
.flex > div{
  background:#aaa
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
      Text to check
  </div>
    <div>
      Text to check for similar width
  </div>
   <div>
      Text to check for similar width - will it work
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer! Also,  it's posible changing align-items: stretch; on the container

Answer (score 5):

No need to use flex or floats at all.

Simply give the parent container a display declaration of `inline-block`.

The width of the parent will expand to accommodate the width of the widest child - but no more.

Meanwhile, since all the children are block-level elements, *their* width will all expand to match the width of the parent container.

**ie.** *all child block-level elements will be displayed at the same width as the widest child element.*

**Example:**

```css
.inline-block {
display: inline-block;
}

.inline-block > div {
margin: 6px;
padding: 12px;
background-color:#aaa
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-block">
<div>Text to check</div>
<div>Text to check for similar width</div>
<div>Text to check for similar width - will it work?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Plus 1 for great browser support :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.flex {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
.flex > div {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
      Text to check
  </div>
    <div>
      Text to check for similar width
  </div>
   <div>
      Text to check for similar width - will it work
  </div>
</div>
```

No need for flex. You can try like this.